# Cocos2dx Style and Implementation

Tags: c++, singleton, cocos2d-x

I'm sort of getting back into cocos2dx development. This time I would like to fully understand the subtleties of the library. I have begun to get a good understanding of singleton classes, which they use throughout. I do have a question about their implementation. Here is a basic example of a singleton class being used

```
class GlobalClass
{
    int m_value;
  public:
    GlobalClass(int v = 0)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
    int get_value()
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    void set_value(int v)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
};

// Default initialization
GlobalClass *global_ptr = 0;

void foo(void)
{
  // Initialization on first use
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  global_ptr->set_value(1);
  cout << "foo: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

void bar(void)
{
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  global_ptr->set_value(2);
  cout << "bar: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  cout << "main: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

My question is about the initialization that comes after class definition and before foo, bar, and main. Essentially, I am interested in this line

```
GlobalClass *global_ptr = 0;
```

Where is the stack instance being initialized? You need some interface for that global pointer to the heap that is the member of that stack instance, right? If so, where is this done in cocos2dx?

My other question is about the use of the scope resolution operator (::) to call methods such as in

```
glview = GLViewImpl::create("MyView")
```

What purpose does this serve? Is this to overstep name spacing to access singleton instances?

If any of my understandings are wrong, especially on singletons, please correct them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Syntax of your Singleton class is wrong.

It should be like this :

```
class GlobalClass
{
    static GlobalClass* _instance;  // Make private so only can access with method to avoid NPE for first time access 
    GlobalClass(int v = 0)          // Make constructor private, you can't create object outside the class        
    {
        m_value = v;
    }

    int m_value;
public:
    static GlobalClass* getInstance();

    int get_value()
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    void set_value(int v)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
};

GlobalClass* GlobalClass::_instance = 0;

GlobalClass* GlobalClass::getInstance() {

    return GlobalClass::_instance == nullptr ? GlobalClass::_instance = new GlobalClass : GlobalClass::_instance;
}

void foo(void)
{
    auto global_ptr = GlobalClass::getInstance();   
    global_ptr->set_value(1);
    std::cout << "foo: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

void bar(void)
{
    auto global_ptr = GlobalClass::getInstance();
    global_ptr->set_value(2);
    std::cout << "bar: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto global_ptr = GlobalClass::getInstance();
    std::cout << "main: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
    foo();
    bar();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

And your second question :

Why we use or having static method `create()` almost in all class of cocos2d-x

- In cocos2d-x we create object in two phase

  ```
  - Create Object           // No game Logic only set default_values
  - Initialize Object
  ```
- We're using `Reference Count` mechanism for memory management in cocos2d-x. [what is it ?](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/reference_count_and_autoreleasepool_in_cocos2d-x#Reference-Count)

These `2-phase constructor` and `auto-released reference count` together into a static function: `create()`

Comment: I wasn't my code. I was just an example I found here. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1

Comment: There is two section `Before` and `After` in your given link, You pasted code from 1st section please look second section.

Comment: why is it called with the :: operator?

Comment: The `::` operator is scope resolution operator, can be use to refer static members of the class.

Comment: Im assuming all members need to be static because a singleton approach is used? IE all getInstance functions are static. All constructors are private and accessed from static methods like create()?

Comment: No need to keep all methods of singleton class to be static. bad design :( , Only static `getInstance()` is enough. constructor should be private so that you can't create object outside the class. you should not relate `create()` method with Singleton design pattern, both are different things. like as in example `Sprite` class of cocos2d-x has `create()` method but that is not singleton class.

Comment: Ok, so if we have a sprite class and the sprite class has one member that is a pointer to a sprite class, how do we get multiple sprites at once? Can a singleton class contain multiple different references? Wasnt the paradigm implemented so that only one instance ever existed on the heap? If i assign multiple pointers to that object, wont they be referencing the same object?

Comment: `sprite class has one member that is a pointer to a sprite class` ? `multiple sprite at once` ? **Sprite is not singleton**.